# Converting MongoQuery to C# statement

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

I'm searching for a value in an array of a sub arrays. What will the code in C# look like?

```
db.File.find({
Properties: {
    $elemMatch: {
        $elemMatch: {
            $in: 
                ['AWS-Uploaded']            
            }
        }
    }
});
```

A simplified version of the documents looks like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4f3b83acec76021c6827769e"),
  "Extension" : ".mov",
  "Length" : NumberLong(7910975),
      "Properties" : [
      ["MediaId", "20898180"], 
      ["AWS-Uploaded", "11/08/2013 16:15:50"]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the query object for returning documents where an array element exists, this should do the job

```
Query.ElemMatch("Properties", 
             Query.Exists('AWS-Uploaded',true)
               );
```

To use ElemMatch with query operators, like where `MediaId=20898180` would be:

```
Query.ElemMatch("Properties", 
             Query.EQ('MediaId',20898180)
               );
```

Hope that helps